# Are the District 9 viral websites still accessible?

Tags: district-9

Two in-universe websites were created to promote the movie *District 9*, http://www.multinationalunited.com and http://mnuspreadslies.com. However, both now redirect to the Sony webpage for the film.

Is there anyway to access the original sites, through an internet archive service or other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can punch these into archive.org's Wayback Machine and get the following:

1. [Multinationalunited](https://web.archive.org/web/20080731061751/http://www.multinationalunited.com/)
2. [MNUSpreadsLies](https://web.archive.org/web/20110514150640/http://www.mnuspreadslies.com/)

You can go through the website using the bar at the top.